# Control an external process with PHP

Tags: php, json, external-process

I have a web page where I show the status of some processes (in a table, one row for each process). The user have the options to start the process or to force it to stop.

When the user click to start a process, a JSON object is send to a web service that (using PHP) start the process, like below:

```
<?php
    $params = json_decode($_POST["object"]);
    /** Do something with the params **/

    // Start a external process in background (I'm using 'ls' as an example)
    exec("ls &", $output);

    /** Finish the script **/
```

The problem is: this external process can take several minutes to complete. So, I would like to give the option to stop it. What I want is: when the user click the "stop" button, it will send a JSON object to a web service (in the same server, of course) to stop the process.

How do I keep track of the external process? How do I force it to stop if needed? And how do I make the user to have the control over it?
Is it possible in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start your process with `&` the process is running in background and you get the process id as return. So you could save that pid in a session for example and kill that process if needed.

For this you can use the [posix_kill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-kill.php) command. Perhaps you can then trigger your event and send another request to stop that process.

Comment: I'll try it. But what if the user lost the session? =/

Comment: I don't know how long your script is running. Save the start time and the pid in a database and clean it up with a cron every few minutes.

Comment: I tried a little example, but `exec` does not give the pid. Is there any other PHP command that can give me this info?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use Cron. When user clicked start process button, php change for example value in mysql. Cron every minute check database value and can start process.